# How to create a type alias for an unbound generic lambda in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, lambda, types

I'd like to simplify the following construct:

```
const lambda: <T>(source: Thing<T>) => Other<T> = <T>(source: Thing<T>) => ...
```

by introducing a type alias:

```
type Lambda<T> = (source: Thing<T>) => Other<T>;
const lambda: Lambda<T> = <T>(source: Thing<T>) => ...
```

When I do this, I get the following error at the declaration of the lambda:
    cannot find name 'T'

What is the proper way to specify the type of the lambda?

Comment: The reason you can't use `<T>` there is because it doesn't exist until the function is declared after the equals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There reason this does not work is `Lambda` is a generic type that is a non generic function (once you specify the they for`Lambda` that type is set in stone for the function. The original function on the other hand is a generic function, it can accept any type parameter when called.

To define a type alias for a generic function, the syntax is

```
type Lambda = <T>(source: Thing<T>) => Other<T>;
const lambda: Lambda = <T>(source: Thing<T>) => ...
```